# Angular form inside directive with isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a form like this

```
<ng-form name="investorQuestionaireForm" ng-show="user && user.investorType">
    <input 
        type="radio" 
        required
        name="recesso" 
        ng-model="investorQuestionaire.recesso" 
        ng-change="investorQuestionaireValidation('recesso', investorQuestionaireForm)"/> 
    <input 
        type="radio" 
        required
        name="recesso" 
        ng-model="investorQuestionaire.recesso"
        ng-change="investorQuestionaireValidation('recesso', investorQuestionaireForm)"/>
</ng-form>
```

This form is inside a directive:

```
angular.module('crowdcoreApp').directive('investorForm',function(){
    templateUrl: 'views/template/equity_investor_form.html',
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        project: '=project'
    },
});
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I click on the radio button, the value of `investorQuestionaire.recesso` is not updated, the `ng-change`function is not triggered and most of all the `radio` button, still result as pristine (both in the html class and in the directive scope). I think that there are some problems with the data binding...

Any suggestion on the possible fault of this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radio buttons do not seem to have values.

Add some values to your radio buttons and try it again. For example

```
<ng-form name="investorQuestionaireForm" ng-show="user && user.investorType">
<input 
    type="radio" 
    required
    value="option1"
    name="recesso" 
    ng-model="investorQuestionaire.recesso" 
    ng-change="investorQuestionaireValidation('recesso', investorQuestionaireForm)"/> 
<input 
    type="radio" 
    required
    value="option2"
    name="recesso" 
    ng-model="investorQuestionaire.recesso"
    ng-change="investorQuestionaireValidation('recesso', investorQuestionaireForm)"/>
</ng-form>
```